# Network configuration

Tags: networking

I know that it is a very noob question but I don't how to solve this. I'm using a windows machine with the following network settings:

IP: 192.168.0.104
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.0.1

I need to ping a development board which have the IP 192.168.7.2, but it always return "Request timed out".

I guess I need to change the mask in order to reach the board, but what mask should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set your PC to IP address 192.168.7.3 and netmask 255.255.255.0. You can leave PC without default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the request has timed out means that your gateway has no route to 192.168.7.0/24. If the machine is in the same broadcast domain, you may change the IP like jpou said.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a multifaceted problem but we can start with the network mask.

**Simplified description**: The network mask tells the routing devices on which network you're on. While using a 255.255.255.0 mask the router interprets this is 'everything that begins with 192.168.0 is on my network'. Therefore if the network address you're trying to reach is on the 172.168.7 network, the router will not be able to pass traffic to it.

So to start you can change the network mask on **both** machines to 255.255.0.0 and the router will understand that everything that starts with 192.168 is on it's network and is routable.

This is one specific solution related to the network mask but can be solved multiple ways.